# How can I link two addresses using a Google Sheets formula to create a Google Maps URL?

Tags: formulas, google-sheets, google-maps

It seems that it is easy enough to get the URL to one address using the following formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=",L13),"MAP")
```

Where L13 is an address.

However, I am interested in creating a URL that links two addresses together, so that when I click the hyperlink, it will process it as if I had entered two separate addresses and asked for directions.  Perhaps this requires Apps Script, but if not I'd love to see a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps accepts the address format `Hyde Park, London to Trafalgar Sq, London`, so you can put the start address in `L13` and the destination in `M13` and concatenate the two together like this:

`=hyperlink("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" & L13 & " to " & M13, "directions")`

Answer (score 0):

### Map Directions: Two or More Locations

To generate the URL you can simply use `"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"` joined to two or more locations delimited using the slash `"/"`.  This can be done using `&` or the JOIN function.

#### Example Data

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | Columbia University |
| **2** | National Museum of Mathematics |
| **3** | United Nations Headquarters |
| **4** | Times Square, Manhattan |
| **5** | The Metropolitan Museum of Art |
| **6** | Central Park Zoo |
| **7** | Empire State Building |
| **8** | Museum of Ice Cream |

#### Example Formulas

Either of the following formulas would work

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" &
   JOIN("/",TOCOL(A:A,1)))
```

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" 
   & A1 & "/" & A2 & "/" & A3 & "/" & A4 & "/"
   & A5 & "/" & A6 & "/" & A7 & "/" & A8)
```

Maps will regenerate the URL similar to:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Columbia+University,+116th+and+Broadway,+New+York,+NY+10027,+United+States/National+Museum+of+Mathematics,+11+E+26th+St,+New+York,+NY+10010,+United+States/United+Nations+Headquarters,+405+E+42nd+St,+New+York,+NY+10017,+United+States/Times+Square,+Manhattan,+NY+10036,+United+States/The+Metropolitan+Museum+of+Art,+1000+5th+Ave,+New+York,+NY+10028,+United+States/Central+Park+Zoo,+East+64th+Street,+New+York,+NY+10021,+United+States/Empire+State+Building,+20+W+34th+St.,+New+York,+NY+10001,+United+States/MUSEUM+OF+ICE+CREAM,+558+Broadway,+New+York,+NY+10012,+United+States/@40.7712554,-74.0521721,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m49!4m48!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2f63e96d30dc9:0x577933f947e52750!2m2!1d-73.9625727!2d40.8075355!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c259a6f4d60159:0x8798ba3704f2bc28!2m2!1d-73.987093!2d40.7435349!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2591ce0874d11:0xc5fae28bdd3df635!2m2!1d-73.9674781!2d40.749168!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c25855c6480299:0x55194ec5a1ae072e!2m2!1d-73.9855426!2d40.7579747!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c25896f660c26f:0x3b2fa4f4b6c6a1fa!2m2!1d-73.963244!2d40.7794366!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c258f1fcd66869:0x65d72e84d91a3f14!2m2!1d-73.9718335!2d40.767778!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c259a9b3117469:0xd134e199a405a163!2m2!1d-73.9856644!2d40.7484405!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c259e713d43875:0xbfd5eb3c3e1bb328!2m2!1d-73.9979167!2d40.7238545?entry=ttu
```

[image]

[image]