# How can I link many addresses using a Google Sheets formula to create a Google Maps URL?

Tags: google-sheets, google-maps

[This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170290/) showed how to link two addresses with a formula and open a route with a Google Map link:

```
=hyperlink("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" & D3 & " to " & D4, "directions")
```

But, I don`t know how to create a formula for linking more than two addresses and opening a route with a Google Map link.

Do you know how I could add more addresses to the formula?

How can I link two addresses using a Google Sheets formula to create a Google Maps URL?

Comment: See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171161/) that addresses your question